# CRLF replace asp.net inline

Tags: asp.net

I need some help with the correct syntax to perform a replace via asp.net inline

```
<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Replace( Environment.NewLine, "<br />") Bind("stTxt") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Just need a quick easy fix to display carriage return/line feeds.

Comment: Why not do the replace in code-behind instead?

Comment: Just trying to keep it out of the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
Text='<%# Eval("stTxt").ToString().Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>") %>'
```

Comment: Parser Error Message: A call to Bind was not well formatted.  Please refer to documentation for the correct parameters to Bind. Thanks though, I'll try anything else you come up with, my million combinations haven't worked yet.

Comment: @marc11h: Seems correct to me but could you try replacing `Bind` by `Eval`? Also, could you show more of your aspx? I'd like to see some context